# how to add cell to uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a new cell to a UITableview with an IBAction but when I push the add button on the simulator nothing happens. After hours of research on stackoverflow and google I have come up with this code. I think it should work but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

Please help!!!!

My .h file

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController{
NSMutableArray *countries;
}


- (IBAction)addFav:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;



@end
```

and my .m file

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"


@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController{

}
@synthesize tableView1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
countries = [NSMutableArray new];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [countries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}


- (IBAction)addFav:(id)sender {
[tableView1 beginUpdates];
[countries addObject:@"Finland"];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([countries count] - 1) inSection:0];
[self.tableView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView1 endUpdates];
[tableView1 reloadData];
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Jst try `countries =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in `viewDidLoad`..

Comment: thanks Ox for the swift response, that stopped the app from crashing but when I hit the add button the cell isn't added.

Comment: Thanks HRM, I tried that and the app doesn't crash again but the cell doesn't get added.

Comment: How many sections do you have? Your line `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([countries count] - 1) inSection:1];` *might* have to be `inSection:0`.

Comment: It only has one section, I changed the code to inSection:0 but it still doesn't add

Comment: Where is the IBAction for the button? and have you called [UITableView reloadData]; ?

Comment: Hi Arbitur you can see the IBAction for the button at the bottom of my .m file. Have just tried adding [UITableView reloadData]; to the end of my code but still doesn't work... Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only adding one item at a time, you can consider modifying your `addFav` method to the following:

```
- (IBAction)addFav:(id)sender {
    //[tableView1 beginUpdates];
    [countries addObject:@"Finland"];
    //NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([countries count] - 1) inSection:0];
    //[self.tableView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    //[tableView1 endUpdates];
    [tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

Also, you should be registering your `HomeViewController` to the `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource` protocols in your `.h` file.

Change your line to:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
```

Then within IB/Storyboard you need to link the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets of your `tableView1` under the Connections Inspector to your `HomeViewController`.

Comment: Thanks yazid, I'm trying this now but it still doesn't work but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shayno Can you describe what results you're getting from your app? Is there any data already pre-loaded? Also, can you please post your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method. Sometimes some people (even myself) forget to change the default code from `return 0` to returning the actual number of sections.

Comment: Okay so I wasn't calling the numberOfSectionsInTableView at all before. I have just updated my code with numberOfSectionsInTableView return 1. There is no preloaded data in my tableView. The app is very basic. It's just for my own learning really. I have a tableView at the bottom of a viewController and a button at the top. When I push the button I want to add a cell to the tableView with the title Finland. At the moment when i push the button absolutely nothing happens. I will update my question again so it shows all the changes I have made to the code. Thanks again Yazid

Comment: @Shayno With `numberOfSectionsInTableView` implemented, have you tried using *just* my suggested code from this answer for your `addFav` method?

Comment: Yes I did but still no cell is added

Comment: @Shayno I just realized also, you should be registering your `HomeViewController` to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol in your `.h` file. Change your line to `@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>{`, then within IB/Storyboard you need to link the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets of your `tableView1` under the Connections Inspector to your `HomeViewController`.

Comment: Just needed to change my .h file like you said. thanks again!